# Make view scrollable with IB

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to make the content of view scrollable using IB ?

I know how to do that programmatically, but can't figure out how to that using IB. I have googled, but didn't found useful solution.

Comment: you googled, but didn't look at components in IB ?

Comment: and what is your view a UIView or something else?

Comment: When I drop ScrollView over my View in IB it hides the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to drag a scroll view widget from right-side panel under objects onto the .xib file's view. You can then add other views inside the scroll view by dragging. In this exam I've dragged a UILabel view onto the scroll view to place it inside. You can see the view hierarchy on the left in Xcode.

I've attached a screenshot that shows a section of Xcode 4 which should demonstrate everything you need! Note that the view hierarchy here is as follows:

UIView (Standard UIView that was created by Xcode when I made the .xib user interface file) > UIScrollView > UILabel

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is what I do. In my .h file I have UIScrollView outlet which is connected with the srollview in IB. Then in my .m file I create some UI's programmatically. Then I add them to UIScrollView.
[self.scrollView addSubView:UIelement]; The problem is that the window is no scrollable.

Comment: set the contentSize property of UiScrollView programmatically. and make sure width of ContentSize greater than the width of self.View if you want scrollable Horizontally. same for vertically also.